# Markov Chain: Optimal stopping to determine the price at which stock is traded

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, finance

The stock price starts at 100\$. At any given time, there is 50% probability that stock price increases further by 1 and 50% probability that stock price goes back to 100\$. You are paying 1\$ to trade. What price should you trade this stock if it starts moving upwards?

I tried modeling this problem as markov chain but was soon lost due to lack of experience. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if the stock price reaches $0$? Can it go further down?

Comment: @callculus the stock price either increase by 1 or goes back to 100. So, it won't reach zero ever. Apologies, I messed up the wording of question. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43968

Answer (score 0):

You should never do anything. Each time you pay \$1 and it either goes up by \$1 (in which case you really haven't gained anything), or goes to \$100 from above (this could be no change, if at \$100 already, but could be a loss). So either you get no benefit, or you get a loss.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "$1 to trade" means you only pay when you actually trade (i.e. sell the stock at its current price).  You dont pay anything to simply hold the stock, and there is no depreciation / net present value kind of consideration.

Under this model I think the question is ill-defined.  If you wait infinitely long, the stock price will reach any arbitrarily high value.  (Equivalently, if you keep flipping a fair coin infinitely many times, you will see arbitrarily long streaks of Heads.)  So if you want to sell at say $1 billion, simply wait really, REALLY long until the price reaches \$1 billion, then sell.  It will eventually happen, and the model of the question does not penalize such waiting.  Alas, that is not the optimal solution since another strategy to wait till \$2 billion will beat it (after waiting even longer).